# How can i add a string to the beginning of every line in a file with sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file which has 7375 lines and i need to add `ls -l` to the beginning of every line. How could i do this with `sed`?

Comment: `sed '/^/ls -l /' my_file` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the beginning of a line with `^` and replace it with your desired string `ls -l` with `sed`'s `s/search/replace/`

Your command would look like:

```
$ sed 's/^/ls -l /' file
```